# Using Unity's new Input Action system, is there a way to get all other keys not binded?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to get keys pressed that are not in your current bindings?

Use Case: I have the player control buttons mapped, but if they press something else, say another letter or number or any other key on the keyboard, I want to display the control scheme back to them.

With the old Input System I could use say Input wasn't one of the other keys, but now I'm not so sure if that's possible, without creating a binding for all the other keys.

Comment: The fun part about programming is everything is just data, so as long as you know how to find the data you need and manipulate it, anything is possible. I have not used the new input system, but after looking over the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/ActionAssets.html) a bit, I believe it is possible although quite annoying. The docs have actions that contain KeyCodes similar to the old system. I would build a HashSet of all inputs that are contained in the actions.

Comment: After I would detect which key is pressed, but that seems [rather difficult right now](https://forum.unity.com/threads/check-if-any-key-is-pressed.763751/) and if the key pressed is not contained in your Hashset, then display the data you would like.